# Constant term in the periodic Poisson equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons

When we solve the Poisson equation with periodic boundary conditions we have to ensure that the integral of the right hand side is zero. That is, we neglect the constant term of the Fourier expansion of the right hand side.

What is the physical significance of this? How does it affect the Hartree potential (equation
$\nabla^2 V = -4 \pi \rho$)?

Comment: Possibly relevant is the fact that a spatially constant $\rho$ gives an ill-posed Poisson problem. Because you must have $\nabla^2 V \neq 0 $ but this in turn implies $\vec{E}\neq\vec{0}$ which violates the symmetry of the situation.